# Postgres not using Index for seemingly no reason

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a table, `items`, with about 18 million rows.

I want to be able to quickly retrieve where `market > 0`. This means that the item is on sale, and the `market` value as its price. To do so, I placed an partial Index on `market` where `market > 0`.

I'm expecting about a few thousand tables to be occupied where `market > 0`. What I don't understand is why Postgres isn't using the Index on it, and instead using GATHER + SEQ Scan.

Shown below is my index.
[image: My Index]

And this is my query:
`EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM gamecards WHERE market > 0`

which gives me this:

```
Gather  (cost=1000.00..472915.53 rows=1 width=75) (actual time=1435.901..1555.273 rows=0 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on items  (cost=0.00..471915.43 rows=1 width=75) (actual time=1430.694..1430.694 rows=0 loops=3)
        Filter: (market <> 0)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 7575337
Planning Time: 0.131 ms
Execution Time: 1555.312 ms
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hmm. Are you 100% sure that execution plan matches your query? I'm seeing `market <> 0` in the execution plan, which is obviously different then the `market > 0` you said you were using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has

```
WHERE market <> 0
```

To support that, your inde would have to be defined as

```
CREATE INDEX ON items (market) WHERE market <> 0;
```

To use a partial index, there has to be a `WHERE` condition in the query that the optimizer can prove to be at least as strong as the index condition. The optimizer's smartness is limited.

Comment: Man I have no clue why but that works now (I changed query from != to >, as I don't need "negative" value items) - I made a full index before as well but it didn't work out and now somehow it did. I probably did something wrong. Thanks!